# Is there any way to work with Win32 C++ source in visual environment?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, mfc

I have source code of C++ project "DDF195", I tried to make some change in form operation and style.

I need to know how I can open form in visual environment?
I just found this file about project.

```
================================================================================
    MICROSOFT FOUNDATION CLASS LIBRARY : DDF195 Project Overview
===============================================================================

The application wizard has created this DDF195 application for 
you.  This application not only demonstrates the basics of using the Microsoft 
Foundation Classes but is also a starting point for writing your application.

This file contains a summary of what you will find in each of the files that
make up your DDF195 application.

DDF195.vcproj
    This is the main project file for VC++ projects generated using an application wizard. 
    It contains information about the version of Visual C++ that generated the file, and 
    information about the platforms, configurations, and project features selected with the
    application wizard.

DDF195.h
    This is the main header file for the application.  It includes other
    project specific headers (including Resource.h) and declares the
    CDDF195 application class.

DDF195.cpp
    This is the main application source file that contains the application
    class CDDF195.

DDF195.rc
    This is a listing of all of the Microsoft Windows resources that the
    program uses.  It includes the icons, bitmaps, and cursors that are stored
    in the RES subdirectory.  This file can be directly edited in Microsoft
    Visual C++. Your project resources are in 1033.

res\DDF195.ico
    This is an icon file, which is used as the application's icon.  This
    icon is included by the main resource file DDF195.rc.

res\DDF195.rc2
    This file contains resources that are not edited by Microsoft 
    Visual C++. You should place all resources not editable by
    the resource editor in this file.

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

For the main frame window:
    The project includes a standard MFC interface.

FrameWndMainForm.h, FrameWndMainForm
    These files contain the frame class CFrameWndMainForm, which is derived from
    CFrameWnd and controls all SDI frame features.

res\Toolbar.bmp
    This bitmap file is used to create tiled images for the toolbar.
    The initial toolbar and status bar are constructed in the CFrameWndMainForm
    class. Edit this toolbar bitmap using the resource editor, and
    update the IDR_MAINFRAME TOOLBAR array in DDF195.rc to add
    toolbar buttons.
```

I just managed to fix some error like Cbrush usage and some missed library, and can run project. Now I need to make some change in form view!
In solution I can found some file with .h and .cpp Suffix same as frmMain.

Source code is from: https://www.rohde-schwarz.com/ product

Comment: You probably should modify the title. Of course you can use Visual Studio for what you want.

Comment: @Ron i try to read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/resource-files-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @drescherjm May you send some tutorial link ?

Comment: I don't have a good tutorial. I did write a around million lines of code in MFC at work but it's been 11 years since I have worked with MFC.

Comment: You may find that the following site is a good `MFC` resource: https://www.codeproject.com/

Comment: I can do that when i understand what is MFC, i post asnwer . Thanks for help and please mark as answer.
@drescherjm

Comment: Rohde & Schwarz GmbH & Co. KG surely have a library where you will find a copy of Jeff Prosise' [Programming Windows with MFC](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1572316950).

Comment: I expect that book is somewhere on my bookshelf right behind me here at work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello After 8 or more hour i can open form as visual.
In Solution Explorer > Aim Project > Resources File > [Name].rc > Double Click
If we open rc file as code we get error it is open with another application, Close all code tab in VC then try again new tree menu appear , on Dialog directory we can find and open all form and then for edit event on form we should use cpp file.
**Special thanks to @Ron and @drescherjm**